# Почему в Laravel в DOM дереве может не отображаться форма?

Tags: laravel

Всем привет, почему в Laravel в DOM дереве может не отображаться форма?

имеется главная форма в которой есть другие формы. Вот код

```html
<form action="{{ route('profile.adverts.closed') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="profile-published-advert__delete-all">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/>
                    <button>Продлить выбранные</button>
                    <button>Удалить выбранные</button>
                </div>

                @foreach ($adverts as $advert)
                    <div class="profile-published-advert__item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <ul class="profile-advert-container__number">
                                    @if ($advert->getRemainingDays($advert->expires_at) < 3)
                                        <li class="profile-published-advert__last-days-alert-danger">
                                            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.extend', $advert) }}">
                                                @csrf
                                                <button>Продлить</button>
                                            </form>
                                        </li>
                                    @endif
                                    <li>
                                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.edit', $advert) }}">
                                            @csrf
                                            <button>Редактировать</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.close', $advert) }}">
                                            @csrf
                                            <button>Закрыть</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </form>
```

вроде как все верно, но столкнулся с такой проблемой. Не отображается данная форма( при клике на кнопку Продлить происходит редирект на родительский роут route('profile.adverts.closed')

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.extend', $advert) }}">
     @csrf
     <button>Продлить</button>
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В HTML не может одна форма находится внутри другой. Используйте атрибут formaction

Пример:

```
<form method="POST">
@csrf
<div class="profile-published-advert__delete-all">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/>
    <button type="submit" formaction="{{ route('profile.adverts.closed') }}">Продлить выбранные</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="{{ route('profile.adverts.closed') }}">Удалить выбранные</button>
</div>

@foreach ($adverts as $advert)
<div class="profile-published-advert__item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <ul class="profile-advert-container__number">
                @if ($advert->getRemainingDays($advert->expires_at) < 3)
                <li class="profile-published-advert__last-days-alert-danger">
                    <button type="submit"  formaction="{{ route('profile.extend', $advert) }}">Продлить</button>
                </li>
                @endif
                <li>
                    <button type="submit"  formaction="{{ route('profile.edit', $advert) }}">Редактировать</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="submit"  formaction="{{ route('profile.close', $advert) }}">Закрыть</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас где-то в верстке существует не закрытый тег form`(</form>)`. Как вариант можно открыть и закрыть `<form></form>` перед формой.